# Do two injective functions prove bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove $|A| = |B|$, and I have two injective functions $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to A$. Is this enough proof for a bijection, which would prove $|A| = |B|$? It seems logical that it is, but I can't find a definitive answer on this.

All I found is [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080426102454AA3UaI7) yahoo answer:

> One useful tool for proving that two sets admit a bijection between
>   them is a theorem which says that if there is an injective function $f: A \to B$ and an injective function $g: B \to A$ then there is a bijective
>   function $h: A \to B$. The theorem doesn't really tell you how to find $h$,
>   but it does prove that $h$ exists. The theorem has a name, but I forget
>   what it is.

But he doesn't name the theorem name and the yahoo answers are often unreliable so I don't dare to base my proof on just this quote.

Comment: It's called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem an wikipedia lists some proofs ... AB,

Comment: @Roy T.: Most proofs of Cantor-Bernsein construct a bijection $h$ explicitly from $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Thanks Martini and André, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes this is true, it is called [Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem).

Comment: Hey, this is exactly the sort of confirmation I was looking for. Thanks!