# Proof that there is a bijection, if there are injective maps in both directions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets.

Let $f:A\to B$ be injective such that $Im(f) \subsetneq B$.

Let $g:B\to A$ be injective such that $Im(g) \subsetneq A$.

Obviously $A$ and $B$ are not finite sets. Can we guarantee an existence of a bijection between $A$ and $B$?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem).

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you! It was driving me insane!

Comment: Similar (duplicate?) question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122498/do-two-injective-functions-prove-bijection, you can also find several questions about Cantor-Bernstein theorem on this site: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Cantor+Bernstein

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In fact, one can show that if there is an injective function from $A$ to $B$ and   an injective function from $B$ to $A$, then there is a bijection from $A$ to $B$. This is known as the [Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem). (Of note is that its proof does not depend on the Axiom of Choice.)

Comment: I knew it was true if $f$ and $g$ are exhaustive, but I had no idea that there was a proof for the injective case.